# Auto-Add Comment to Textbox in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have this text box in Access 2010 that stores a bunch of comments. What I want to do is make it so that when the user can click inside the textbox and WHEN they hit enter, it inserts the day’s date and a pre-set comment (ex. Jul 16-14 Yes) followed by a line of space at the top of the boxs, while still keeping any comments below.

I can get it to insert the date, however it does that as soon as I click inside the textbox and deletes all the other comments that are already there, which is not what I want. I want to keep all the existing comments and just add a new one on top. The On Click event is empty, and the On Enter is set to event procedure.

This is what I have so far – but as mentioned, it only enters the date when I click, and erases everything else. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Comments_Enter()
Comments = Format(Now(), "mmm-dd/yy")
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should work on 1 thing at a time. For now, I think you should work on saving the text that was in the textbox and adding a date to it. I think you may want to check your `Format()` function also. I don't think `Now` requires the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Enter is triggered when you click. It's not related to the 'enter' key.

See this [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211374(v=office.11).aspx) for clarification.

Use the On Click event instead (or the Double Click event if you so choose).

```
Sub Comments_Click()
  Dim strInput as String
  strInput = InputBox("Press enter to save.",,Format(Now(), "mmm-dd/yy") & " Your preset message")
  If strInput <> "" Then
    Programming_Comments = strInput & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Programming_Comments
  End If
End Sub
```

The key is to save your new string AND the old string into the Programming_Comments field.